# R: How to transform dataframe into .hyper?

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am an R & tableau user. My object is to extract a dataframe in R and transform it into .hyper format, so that my tableau can read the dataframe directly.

Why I am not considering extract a csv format which can also be read by tableau? Because the .csv file is too large (about 1.7 GB) and there is no way to shrank my dataframe anymore. I hope there is way to extract .hyper and that's not a super large file. Thanks!

Comment: The Extract API doesn't support R but does support C, C++, Java and Python. You could use something like r2py https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/r_interface.html to convert the R dataframe to Pandas in python then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

[pantabR](https://github.com/Btibert3/pantabR) should support your use case

To cite from their README:

```
devtools::install_github("btibert3/pantabR")
library(pantabR)
dat = data.frame(x=1:10, y=letters[1:10])
frame_to_hyper(dat, f="dataset.hyper", tbl="dataset")
```